# How to render a bound bulleted list in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I would like to have a column in a table in a SSRS report display as a bulleted list of items.  The values for this would be pulled from the database.  I would like to set the ListStyle property of the textbox to Bulleted, so that I can make sure each item is indented properly when it wraps to a new line.  How can I do this?  Perhaps there is a certain delimiter I can use to concatenate the values together so that each item is rendered as a bulleted item in a list.

I realize I can append a new line and a bullet character between each item, but then they are not indented properly when the item wraps.  If I had SSRS 2016 I could have the text box render as HTML and append the appropriate HTML to it, but that's not an option at this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this to work using a subreport.  The subreport contains a table with two columns, the first contains the bullet symbol and the other contains the text.  If the text wraps to the second line, it's indented just fine because it stays in the column.  Though it would be nice if there was a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Custom code method would be your only route. This code will have to be changed to include what character you would like to the line to split at. assuming there is a character within the field already to split by. chr(149) is the bullet point.

```
Public Function SplitNextLine(ByVal strSplit As String) As String
Dim strArr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sReturn As String = ""
Dim check As String = "vbCrLf"

strArr = strSplit.Split(vbCrLf)

For i = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
If i = 0 Then
sReturn += strArr(i)
Else
sReturn += vbCrLf & Chr(149) & strArr(i)
End If
Next

Return sReturn
End Function
```

When referencing this code in the textboxes on the face of the report you would use...

```
Code.SplitNextLine(YourFieldNameGoesHere)
```

Comment: If a value in the list has to wrap to the next line, I don't see how this will indent the wrapped text.

Comment: You are only going to get that functionality with HTML. SSRS isnt inteligent enough to re-produce a result like that. I'm assuming that's why they integrated that functionality in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes have a `HangingIndent` property. This applies to lines of text that are wrapped to a new line. You must give it a negative value such as `-20pt`. I would suggest leaving each item in its own row instead of trying to concatenate them. That way you can let the report handle the formatting for you instead of resorting to custom code.

If needed, you can place a table with 1 cell into the spot where you want this list (even in another table). That cell will be repeated for each instance of the grouping. As long as there's no border, it will look just like a single bulleted list.

Comment: Sorry, I played with this but wasn't able to get your suggestion to work.  Nested tables didn't work either because it would require a different dataset.

Comment: That's where the `Lookup` function comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the Chr with a String:
`"" & Chr(0149)`